# Is it possible to change mount options of an existing encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 installation using a live stick?

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount

Today I unintentionally changed the mount options of my main harddrive. After I enter the decryption phrase during the bootup the Ubuntu logo and the loading bar show up and afterwards the screen turns black and stays black. Is there any possibility to start the system and change the options again? Is it possible to change the settings with a live boot using an usb stick? Is it possible to access the harddrive if I know the key phrase?

Comment: Never tried it but since you have the key you can try the liveusb option!

Comment: Solved it by booting with liveusb and copying the data to an external hard drive. Thanks for your help @GeorgeUdosen.

Comment: Please can you share those details in an answer? Great it worked out!

Comment: Please can you share those details in an answer? Great it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not fix the original error. As suggested by @GeorgeUdosen, I booted with liveusb. I was able to decrypt my original drive using `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda3/`. The drive was automatically mounted and I could copy my files to an external drive. Afterwards, I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10.